# PropTypes in react for type checking

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I read in the official react docs that for performance reason proptypes only work in development mode. So what is it's use if they can't be used in production build. Like is there any benefit of using proptypes in development mode?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any benefit of using proptypes in development mode?

That's the *only* place it has any benefit. Prop types is a tool to assist you with development. It gives you log messages pointing out likely bugs in your code, and then you modify your code to get rid of those bugs. If prop types were included in the production build, the log messages it generates would be of no use to the end user.